# Jinja template in Ansible treats "dest" as a directory instead of as a file

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

**tl;dr**
Ansible's template module treats a template destination as a directory instead of as a file. What am I missing?

**Situation:**
I am using paulfantom's ansible-restic role in another role, named `backups-role`. I am testing my role with a dummy playbook in a local lxc environment, which installs a database service and then uses ansible-restic to create a cron job to back it up. For testing purposes, the backup destination is a local restic repo: `/var/backup/backups-test` . I am using only one restic_repo named <s>`backups-test`</s>***Wrong! the variable was named `{{ ansible_hostname }}/{{ ansible_date_time.epoch }}`, evaluated to something equivalent to `myhost.local/1551799877`. See the answer directly.***

**Problem**
This ansible task with from a stable ansible role ([ansible-restic](https://github.com/paulfantom/ansible-restic/blob/master/tasks/configure.yml#L11)):

```
- name: Deploy cron script
  template:
    src: 'restic.cron.j2'
    dest: '/etc/cron.d/restic-{{ item.name }}'
    mode: '0640'
  no_log: false
  with_items: '{{ restic_repos }}'
  register: _cronfiles
```

... fails complaining with:

```
Destination directory /etc/cron.d/restic-backups-test does not exist
```

**Discussion**
What ansible-restic should do here is to deploy a cron script based on a template, with name `restic-backups-test`, inside directory `/etc/cron.d/` . However, it looks like ansible interprets that the directory should be `/etc/cron.d/restic-backups-test` and the file name just the epoch timestamp like `1551799877` , contrary to what [ansible docs](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html?highlight=templates#examples) itself suggests:

```
# Example from Ansible Playbooks
- template:
    src: /mytemplates/foo.j2
    dest: /etc/file.conf
    owner: bin
    group: wheel
    mode: 0644
```

I'm afraid it has to do with my environment instead, but I don't know what could make ansible change this behaviour, and my playbook doesn't do black magic.

**Some more details**
I am running ansible version 2.7.8 with python 3.5.3 from a Debian Stretch machine, against a linux container with guest os Ubuntu Bionic with python 2.7.15rc1 and python 3.6.7 .  python symlink points to python2.7 . I have tried also with python3.6 with the same result.

**Petition**
Can you help me make sense of this? At the end I just want it to work without having to modify the upstream role. The timestamp filename can be a hint you may understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I self-answer becase I solved it with the hints of @[TheLastProject](https://github.com/TheLastProject) from github.com. See just asked:

> What's the value of your restic_repos variable?

And it turned to be that the info I provided at the question was wrong. I was setting the variable with a slash `/` in the middle of the name, still don't know why. Therefore, when `ansible-restic` was trying to make sure that `/etc/cron.d/{{ repo_name }}` existed, it was actually trying to check `/etc/cron.d/myhost.local/1551799877`, which clearly didn't exist, and didn't create it because it only creates files, not intermediary parents.

So no magic and no bugs in Ansible!

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I deleted my answer. No value here. You probably might want to do the same.